# Some users fail to query linked server with "Login failed for user NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON"

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

When I try to run a simple query involving a linked server it fails:

```
SELECT * FROM [server2].[DWH].[dbo].[SomeTable]

Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

But, there is another user who can run this query without problems.

---

Our company doesn't have a SQL Server DBA and we have inherited a few SQL Servers from another company after acquisition.

I'm a developer trying to run some queries and I'm having hard time trying to figure out how to configure access correctly. I don't really know where to look, so I'll try to explain the current setup to the best of my ability.

There is Server1:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64) 
    Aug 15 2017 10:23:29 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

There is Server2:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU15-GDR) (KB4505221) - 13.0.4604.0 (X64) 
    Jun 15 2019 07:56:34 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Our company has a domain `MAIN_DOMAIN` and I log into my Windows laptop as `MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name`. When I run SSMS on my laptop I can connect to both `Server1` and `Server2` using Windows authentication.

As far as I understand, my login in both SQL Servers has pretty much all the permissions:

Server1:

```
CREATE LOGIN [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [serveradmin] ADD MEMBER [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [setupadmin] ADD MEMBER [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [processadmin] ADD MEMBER [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [diskadmin] ADD MEMBER [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name]
```

Server2:

```
CREATE LOGIN [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [serveradmin] ADD MEMBER [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [setupadmin] ADD MEMBER [MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name]
```

**The Server1 and Server2 themselves are not in `MAIN_DOMAIN`, they are in `other_domain.com`**

I can Remote Desktop to both of them using `other_domain\my.name` user with a different password than my main domain user.

This is how the linked server is configured on `Server1`:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'server2', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'server2',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'server2', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
```

On `Server1` the MSSQLSERVER service (sqlservr.exe) runs under user called `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER`.

On `Server2` the MSSQLSERVER service (sqlservr.exe) runs under user called `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER`.

[image: sql server service user]

---

Here is output of `setspn -l`. I get the same output when I run it on `server1` or `server2`:

```
C:\Windows\system32>setspn -l SERVER2
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=SERVER2,OU=Azure Resources,OU=Corporate,DC=other_domain,DC=com,DC=au:
        MSSQLSvc/SERVER2.other_domain.com.au:1433
        MSSQLSvc/SERVER2.other_domain.com.au
        WSMAN/SERVER2
        WSMAN/SERVER2.other_domain.com.au
        TERMSRV/SERVER2
        TERMSRV/SERVER2.other_domain.com.au
        RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER2
        HOST/SERVER2
        RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER2.other_domain.com.au
        HOST/SERVER2.other_domain.com.au

C:\Windows\system32>setspn -l SERVER1
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=SERVER1,OU=Azure Resources,OU=Corporate,DC=other_domain,DC=com,DC=au:
        MSSQLSvc/SERVER1.other_domain.com.au:1433
        MSSQLSvc/SERVER1.other_domain.com.au
        Microsoft Virtual Console Service/SERVER1.other_domain.com.au
        Microsoft Virtual Console Service/SERVER1
        Microsoft Virtual System Migration Service/SERVER1.other_domain.com.au
        Microsoft Virtual System Migration Service/SERVER1
        Hyper-V Replica Service/SERVER1.other_domain.com.au
        Hyper-V Replica Service/SERVER1
        WSMAN/SERVER1
        WSMAN/SERVER1.other_domain.com.au
        TERMSRV/SERVER1.other_domain.com.au
        TERMSRV/SERVER1
        RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER1
        HOST/SERVER1
        RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER1.other_domain.com.au
        HOST/SERVER1.other_domain.com.au
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand what it means. The only thing that I understand here is that `MAIN_DOMAIN` is not mentioned anywhere.

---

A different user can run the query involving linked server without problems.

He logs into `Server1` using Remote Desktop and using `other_domain\his.name`. He runs SSMS on that `Server1` and connects to SQL Server using Windows authentication.

His login on `Server1` has all permissions as well:

```
CREATE LOGIN [other_domain\his.name] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [other_domain\his.name]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [serveradmin] ADD MEMBER [other_domain\his.name]
```

---

What do I need to configure, so that I could run a query involving linked server while I'm connected to SQL Server from my laptop using `MAIN_DOMAIN\my.name` ?

Comment: Do you know if there is a forest or domain trust between the two domains?
Do you know if there is a proper SPN registration for each SQL instance in their domain?

Comment: @MBuschi, thank you for reply. There are sysadmins in the company who configure domain and AD users, but it will take them days to respond to a ticket. There is a lot of bureaucracy. I myself know pretty much nothing about Active Directory, I'm not a sysadmin. **But**, I can remote desktop to each server, run elevated cmd.exe and check myself. Unfortunately, I have no idea what command would give me an answer to your question. If you tell me, I will run it and tell you the output.

Comment: The problem is that windows authentication has a lot of requirement and involves kerberos authentication for two hops made usually by linked server.
You have to manage AD, kerberos and sql spn to solve this issure; so it is mandatory to involve your IT department in it.
You must ask for a trust between the two domain and the proper spn registration for the sql in the middle. You relly need a DBA that can talk with them and ask the proper questions and submit proper needs.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I'm not a SysAdmin myself, more of a developer and quasi-DBA, but I just went through some issues with my linked server and had to check the **SPNs**. The easiest way to do that is RDP to the server itself, open an elevated Command window, and type the command `SETSPN -l ServerName` to get the list of registered **SPNs**, as per Microsoft's Docs on [Setspn - Viewing SPNs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc731241(v=ws.11)). You might also find...

Comment: ...[this document if you use Kerberos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-ver15) helpful as well.

Comment: @J.D., thank you for reply. I've added output of `setspn -l` to the question, but I don't know how it should look like, what is missing or incorrect there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to verify these requirements:

- AD Trust between source domain and target domain
- Proper AD SPN registration at least for the linked server source instance
- You have to verify proper DNS resolution in both domains for TGT requests (Are they in the same AD forest?

Sorry but there is not an easy answer and to set all these things you must have Domain Admin right (or even forest admin)

You can verify by yourself spn for instances with this cmd:

```
setspn -l server1$
setspn -l server2$
```

Take a look at this info about kerberos:

[how to stop using sql server login credentials in a linked server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245236/how-to-stop-using-sql-server-login-credentials-in-a-linked-server/249435#249435)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've added output of `setspn -l` to the question. Unfortunately, I don't understand what it means. I tried to read the question and answer that you linked, but that is way beyond my knowledge. There must be some trust between domains, because I can RDP to `server1` and `server2`. I guess, I'll RDP to `server1` and run SSMS on it.